# GIT pull command with email parameter

Tags: git, pull-request, git-pull, pull

I have been working on the server where git configuration had been already set, so when I was trying to pull my repository, I had to provide password for the account for which configuration was already set or I could change the configuration for a while and then restore it.
Is there any way to pass my email as a parameter to the git pull command so I will not need to change the configuration every time I nedd git pull.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the SSH protocol, you can connect and authenticate to remote servers and services. With SSH keys, you can connect to GitHub without supplying your username or password at each visit.**

Following steps are applicable for a windows machine. For other OS follow this [link](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

If you don't already have an SSH key, you must generate a new SSH key. If you're unsure whether you already have an SSH key, check for existing keys.

If you don't want to reenter your passphrase every time you use your SSH key, you can add your key to the SSH agent, which manages your SSH keys and remembers your passphrase.

**Generating a new SSH key**

1. Open Git Bash.
2. Paste the text below, substituting in your GitHub Enterprise email
   address.

> $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

This creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label.

```
> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
```

3. When you're prompted to "Enter a file in which to save the key,"
   press Enter. This accepts the default file location.

   > Enter a file in which to save the key (/c/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa):[Press enter]
4. At the prompt, type a secure passphrase. For more information, see
   "Working with SSH key passphrases".

   > Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
   >
   > Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]

**Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent**

Before adding a new SSH key to the ssh-agent to manage your keys, you should have checked for existing SSH keys and generated a new SSH key.

If you have GitHub Desktop installed, you can use it to clone repositories and not deal with SSH keys. It also comes with the Git Bash tool, which is the preferred way of running git commands on Windows.

1. Ensure the ssh-agent is running:

   - If you are using the Git Shell that's installed with GitHub Desktop, 
     the ssh-agent should be running.
   - If you are using another terminal    prompt, such as Git for Windows,
     you can use the "Auto-launching the    ssh-agent" instructions in
     "Working with SSH key passphrases", or    start it manually:

   ## start the ssh-agent in the background

   $ eval $(ssh-agent -s)

   > Agent pid 59566
2. Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent. If you created your key
   with a different name, or if you are adding an existing key that has
   a different name, replace id_rsa in the command with the name of
   your private key file.

   $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

[Add the SSH key to your GitHub account.](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)